# Как сделать ограничение с помощью переменной в random.randint()

Tags: python, случайные-числа, aiogram

Недавно я писал бота "угадай число". Сейчас решил добавить кое-какую функцию, но столкнулся с проблемой.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам мог выбрать до какого числа бот будет загадывать свое число.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chet.id, 'Напишите число, от 1 до которого я загадаю число:')
    a = int(message.text)
    await Form.number.set()
    global r
    r = random.randint(1, a)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я загадал число от 1 до ' + str(a) + '. Теперь попробуйте отгадать его. Никаких подсказок! Для выхода /cancel или "выйти".')
```

Но при таком коде выдает ошибку `invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: вам нужно значение получать не через сообщение, а что то типа меню... Что бы однозначно получить нужное. Смотрите документацию к боту.

Comment: Распечатайте message.text там скорее всего не десятичное число.

Comment: И функция int говорит вам об этом.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял из вашего кода, пользователь отправляет команду *start* и вы в этой же функции проверяете что содержится в `message.text`, хотя там будет только команда *start*.

То есть в вашем коде происходит примерно следующее:

```
Если пользователь отправляет команду "start", то
отправить ему сообщение "Напишите число, от 1 до которого я загадаю число:"
Получить, что написал пользователь (будет "start") и преобразовать это в число
```

Так как нельзя преобразовать "start" в число, Python выдаёт ошибку. Также попробуйте вместо вашего кода, написать вот этот:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите число, от 1 до которого я загадаю число:')
    print(message.text, type(message.text))
```

Если в результате у вас будет например:

`1 int`

то возможно проблема в другой части кода, а если там будет:

`start str`

то нужно читать сообщения, приходящие боту и если в предыдущем сообщением была команда *start*, то нужно записать это сообщение (самое последнее), и если будет ошибка, то нужно написать пользователю, чтобы он отправил число ещё раз. Если ошибки не будет, то сгенерировать случайное число и проверять все сообщения пользователя на это число, пока он не угадает